# jQuery methods closest and parent / find not working on certain div

Tags: jquery, find, parent, closest

I have a div with the following content:

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    Cat1: <span class="badge">5</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    Cat2: <span class="badge">3</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="viewComments">Comments:</a> <span class="badge cntComments">2</span>
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Delete</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Add</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the text of the span with class "`cntComments`" using jQuery (so in this case it should return "`2`") but when I alert this out it always shows me a blank alert. I also tried using "parent()" instead of "closest()" but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong here?

**My jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewComments', function() {
    var cntComments = $(this).closest('div.panel-footer').find('cntComments').text();
    alert(cntComments);
    // ...
});
```

Comment: You forgot the `.`, it is `.find('.cntComments');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing class selector `.` in find method:

```
var cntComments = $(this).closest('div.panel-footer').find('.cntComments').text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaa0to2/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot - that's it. :) Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

change `.find('cntComments')` to `.find('.cntComments')` you forgot `.` class selector

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewComments', function() {
var cntComments = $(this).closest('div.panel-footer').find('.cntComments').text();
alert(cntComments);
// ...
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o0Lcrv3w/3/)